# PythonTex Error : No such file or directory on VSCode

Tags: errors, luatex, pythontex, vscode, latex-workshop

```
\documentclass{ltjsarticle}

\usepackage{pythontex}

\begin{pycode}
def fizbuz(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print("fiz", end=' ')
        else:
            print(i, end=' ')
    return
\end{pycode}

\begin{document}
    \pyc{fizbuz(100)}
\end{document}
```

Running this code with Latex Workshop(on VSCode), I have the error: "env: python: No such file or directory". My setting of Latex Workshop is following. How can I solve this problem?

P.S.
I ran the above code on my M1 Mac and I surely installed python3.8 and pygments. The latex engine is LuaLaTeX (TeXLive2021).

```
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
          "name": "toolchain",
          "tools": ["lualatex", "pythontex", "lualatex"]
        }
      ],
      "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
          "name": "lualatex",
          "command": "lualatex",
          "args": [
            "--cmdx",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-halt-on-error",
            "%DOC%"
          ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pythontex",
            "command": "pythontex",
            "args": [
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is no direct answer to your problem, but from my own experience (and because you are already using `LuaLaTeX`, I can really recommend PyLuaTeX to you. It makes it a looot easier to include `Python` code in your `TeX`-files.

I use it a lot when I create plots with `pgfplots` because I find it easier to manage certain variables such as column names, length of lists, …

Also you DO NOT need to compile longer or extra because the code is executed on the fly.

CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/pyluatex?lang=en

Example (just compile with `lualatex` and `--shell-escape`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[executable=python, verbose]{pyluatex} 
% this tells PyLuaTex what your executable in the conosle is, 
% e.g. python, py3, python3, …
% verbose tells PyLuaTeX to print the input and output to the log if you want to see 
% your code being executed

\begin{document}
Hello this a test document. 
We can use python like \py{"this"} or in an environment like this:
\begin{python}
     a = 2 
     b = 3
     c = a * b
     print(c)
\end{python}
% The output is then (obviously) 6. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied/pasted your `recipes` and `tools` snippets in my `settings.json`
but putting the tools item before the recipes one.It worked.

This is my `settings.json`

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash",
    "editor.fontSize": 11,
    "git.suggestSmartCommit": false,
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "python.dataScience.alwaysTrustNotebooks": true,
    "haskell.trace.server": "messages",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "none",
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
          "name": "lualatex",
          "command": "lualatex",
          "args": [
            "--cmdx",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-halt-on-error",
            "%DOC%"
          ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pythontex",
            "command": "pythontex",
            "args": [
                "%DOC%"
            ]
        },
      ]
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        
        {
            "name": "toolchain",
            "tools": ["lualatex", "pythontex", "lualatex"]
        }   
        {
            "name": "latexmk ",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk_rconly"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
            "tools": [
                "lualatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
            "tools": [
                "xelatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex × 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Rnw files",
            "tools": [
                "rnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Jnw files",
            "tools": [
                "jnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "tectonic",
            "tools": [
                "tectonic"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But unfortunately, in my environment, it don't work even though I put "tools" before "recipes". ><